# OpenShift Running Old Kubernetes Version (Minishift)

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, minishift

I have installed the latest Minishift release `1.34.3` on Windows 10 Hyper-V. The OpenShift client version is `4.6.16` as expected however the Kubernetes version is `1.11`.

```
PS C:\Tools> minishift version
minishift v1.34.3+4b58f89

PS C:\Tools> oc version
Client Version: 4.6.16
Kubernetes Version: v1.11.0+d4cacc0
```

From what I understand, OpenShift 4.6 *should* be [running Kubernetes v.1.19](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/release_notes/ocp-4-6-release-notes.html#ocp-4-6-about-this-release) under the hood. How can I upgrade my OpenShift cluster to run a later version of Kubernetes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[minishift](https://github.com/minishift/minishift) is based on OpenShift 3, not the newer OpenShift 4.

> **Note:** Minishift runs OpenShift 3.x clusters. Due to different installation methods, OpenShift 4.x clusters are not supported.

The client, `oc` you are using is a newer version.

Comment: That is my mistake, I assumed my server was running the same version as the oc client. I will look into installing [CodeReady Containers](https://github.com/code-ready/crc#red-hat-codeready-containers---openshift-4-on-your-laptop) as referenced in the GitHub link. Thanks